# Am i able use overripe bananas in pancakes?

Tags: pancakes, bananas

I'm trying to think of a different way to make pancakes and didn't want to throw away a banana I have, that's almost completely brown, but still has a little yellow. I heard you can use overripe bananas to bake, but wasn't sure if maybe i could cook it in a pancake. I'd really appreciate any advice and thank you.

Comment: Have done it many time, and quite good to me.  Be prepared for a bit more cleanup than usual with pancakes.  If they hit the griddle for me, they always stick.

Comment: My grandfather would have said it was just starting to be ripe enough to eat. IOW, your over-ripe banana is perfectly safe, as it's not over-ripe other than "by your expectations, having been trained to eat under-ripe bananas."

Answer (score 4):

Sounds delicious. The ripe banana would work great incorportated into a standard batter - maybe even with a dash of cinnamon/nutmeg (i'm so ready for fall flavours now), or some chocolate chips, or as is!

You can also create a simple "healthy" pancake, with mashed ripe banana and egg mixed together.

Go for it! Ripened bananas are very versatile, flexible and easy to incorporate into most sweet recipes (sugar and starch).

Answer (score 4):

Yes absolutely! It's always a shame when people throw away perfectly good "baking bananas" because they think it is moldy. If you aren't quite ready to use it yet, you can keep dark bananas in your fridge. This will greatly slow the ripening process.

When bananas turn from green to black, a few things are happening:

- Starch is turning into glucose
- Acids are being neutralized
- New aromas are developing

Below is a picture from [Epicurious](http://www.epicurious.com/expert-advice/tricks-for-how-to-ripen-bananas-article) of the ripening process. And yes, you can absolutely get your bananas to turn completely black (assuming you have the patience!).
[image: ripe bananas]

There are 2 ways you could add the banana to pancakes, and it really just depends on which you prefer.

**Chopping the banana** up into cubes no larger than 1/4", and mixing the pieces into the batter. This works best if the banana is firm.

If the banana is very soft, you can **squish the banana up** and then add it to your wet mix. Because it will be adding additional moisture to the batter, reduce the primary liquid (milk?) in the batter by around 1/4 cup. Add additional liquid if needed.